# PHPMailer redirecting to GitHub

Tags: php, phpmailer

When I try to run a simple PHPMailer test script it is redirecting me to GitHub site.

My script is given below. Can someone please help?

```
<?php

    use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
    use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

    require '../PHPMailer/src/PHPMailer.php';


    $mail = new PHPMailer(); // create a new object
    $mail->IsSMTP(); // enable SMTP
    $mail->SMTPDebug = 1; // debugging: 1 = errors and messages, 2 = messages only
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true; // authentication enabled
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls'; // secure transfer enabled REQUIRED for GMail
    $mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";

    $mail->Port = 587; // or 587 or 465
    $mail->IsHTML(true);
    $mail->Username = "myaccountname";
    $mail->Password = "mypassword";
    $mail->setFrom('fromemailid', 'from name');
    $mail->Subject = 'Test Mail';
    $mail->Body = 'Test mail body';
    $mail->AddAddress("someone@gmail.com");

    if (!$mail->send()) 

        {echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
            return false;
        } else {
            return true; 
        }

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Which folder you exactly adding your code. As see your code